# error 500 when D8 site placed in maintenance

Tags: 8, maintenance-mode

Unless connected to admin , putting site in maintenance generate a 500 error.

I have followed [Drupal 8 maintenance page theming](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196205/drupal-8-maintenance-page-theming) instructions, modifying the settings.php and adding the template to the theme but it is still not working .

How can i debug this ?

Comment: you need a more detailed error message, change the settings on /admin/config/development/logging and try again

Comment: it is set with all messages but my syslog does not log anything when reload the 5OO error page

Comment: then drupal is not able to catch the error and you find it in the error log of the webserver, e.g. /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: in nginx/errorlog i got 10368#10368: *6631 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php", Is the server misconfigured?

Answer (score 1):

**BEGINNER VERSION**

Maintenance mode is working in general. Use the following direction of debugging: FROM "untouched" Drupal TO your state.

1. Download a same core version of Drupal as you have. Turn on maintenance mode (without changing anything else), visit the page with a non-admin user.
2. Apply the settings in your link about (Drupal 8 maintenance page theming ) visit again the page with a non-admin user.

Whenever the site brakes you know where the problem resides.

**ADVANCED VERSION**

500 errors are always logged in Drupal. Check what says the "recent log messages" with admin. 
Also you can set in your settings.php

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

This won't just show 500 error, but also tell the reason.

Comment: and what if the error level verbose is already in loca settings but it does not tell the reason still?

Comment: Is local settings loaded by settings.php?
Did you check it in recent log messages?

Comment: die('entering this file') tell me localsettings is loaded

Comment: This is not a chat: I asked two questions, make more effort before answering.

Comment: did i check what in recent log message?the log system is logging things but not when i reload the site with the 5OO error

Comment: Put this into your local.settings.php:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

(however verbose should have done that)